# Comparing several Poisson Models

Tags: modeling, poisson-regression, model-comparison, zero-inflation

I have training data that I have fitted with two types of Poisson models (one zero inflated and one standard) and I would like to compare each model's performance on a test set to see which one is better. How can I do this ? (I am using R if it makes a difference). I have already done chi-squared tests to determine that both fitted Poisson distributions are statistically significant with the training data.

Also, is there a standard way for testing the accuracy of a fitted probability distribution on a test set of data? E.g. like a mean-squared error reduction.

Comment: Some suggestions in this Q&A https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182020/zero-inflated-poisson-regression-vuong-test-raw-aic-or-bic-corrected-results

Comment: You might want to consider using a [quantile-quantile plot]() to see if your fitted probability distribution is a good fit.  A good example is provided [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32048/25629)